# Getting error - No peers available to register a listener and No peers available to query

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have set up hyperledger fabric, and installed and instantiate chaincode for peer0.org1 and peer0.org2 .
I am able to do all transaction for one org. When I tried to do adding peer0.org2 and tried to do transaction through docker cli; I'm able to do all transaction and querying for both org1 and org2.
When I am trying to do these transactions with gateway nodeJS code, I am able to create data from both org, but in org2 creation part getting  error: `[AbstractEventListener]: No peers available to register a listener`
 and in querying I am getting  `error: [SingleQueryHandler]: evaluate: message=No peers available to query`
I am able to do all transactions from docker cli for both org. Docker Logs are as well fine.
Please help to resolve the issue. Thanks in advance.

https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/build_network.html

Comment: could you please share your nodejs code ? how you're trying to achieve it ?